# Cannot log into windows 7 following update

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, login, windows-update

I have exactly the same problem as [Cannot enter password and login - Windows 7 Professional](https://superuser.com/questions/999003/cannot-enter-password-and-login-windows-7-professional), which is that I am trying to login to my computer after the update from windows and upon clicking my login icon, the page just appears to consider it and refresh rather than moving onto the screen where the password can be entered.

Similarly, my background on this screen has been replaced with the background it had when I brought it.

I do not have a touch screen, or a pen. I also do not have a system repair disk.

Fairly certain it was caused by the update as I installed a windows update that has been asking to be installed since the 11th, just like this other person, and I have not done anything else that could affect the computer before login. The problem started occuring immediately after too.

They repaired using system restore. Unfortunately when I go on system restore, my computer does exactly the same thing it does when I try to log in, which is just refresh the page. The automatic selection counter presumably for people without access to their mouse/keyboard similarly refreshes the page. No idea what is going on. Are there any other ways to get the system restored?

Or something else that I think might work, any way to force my pc to use the old fashion system restore dialogue boxes rather than the newer lists? Because I ran an extended service test for the hardware because I have nothing better to do and that worked perfectly.

Instead of what the guide said my F8 options should look like, when I click F8 my pc goes to a page called Advanced Boot Options page the top option being "Repair your computer" this goes to windows which has the options to either Launch Startup Repair (which as I said never gets there) or just continue to login.

Tried all the other options on the page too. Safe modes all just go to login and have the same problem.

Comment: use system restore option to go to the point before Windows installs the updates.

Comment: As I said, I cannot use systems restore because selecting the option merely refreshes the page.

Comment: Did you try your installation DVD. You can used the recover options on the disk, which don't rely on the installed OS.

Answer (score 1):

FIX - Bad Microsoft patch KB3097877

Anyway, this worked for me for the machines stuck at login (safe mode doesn't work, repair doesn't work, SFC doesn't work...)

If you are unable to roll your system back (system restore BEFORE the update), you will have to do this fix from a command line.

1. F8 at post and select "Repair your Computer"
2. Login with an account that has administrative privileges on the machine since you will need to modify system files.
3. Under "Choose a recovery tool" select "Command Prompt"
4. You will need to determine the drive where your OS is installed (this was the trick for me since Microsoft told me to use drive X - which is not correct for the vast majority of systems out there since if you look at the label of the disk, it is BOOT) - easy way just keep switching drive letters (C, D, etc) until you find the disk label that states you are on the "OSDisk"
5. The DISM command is how to remove the patch and I have pasted the command below for both x86 and x64 systems

   ```
   x86 - dism /image:C:\ /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB3097877~31bf3856ad364e35~x86~~6.1.1.1

   x64 - dism /image:C:\ /remove-package /PackageName:Package_for_KB3097877~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.1
   ```

Note that "C" (after image) is the drive labeled OSDisk - you may need to modify or you will get errors

You can also run

```
dism /image:C:\ /get-packages
```

This command lists all updates installed since package name changes for x86 and x64 systems